# RubyMotion AVCaptureDevice error

Tags: ios, avfoundation, rubymotion

I'm currently working my way into RubyMotion and trying to use the iPhone's camera torch. I've "imported" the AVFoundation framework inside my Rakefile but something else seems to be wrong. Do you know of a gem which handles this in a more easy way? I've looked at rubymotion-wrappers.com but couldn't fine one. Thanks in advance.

This is the error I get when the app crashes:

`uninitialized constant Torch::AVMediaTypeVideo (NameError)`

The line where the error comes from is this one (from the following class, line 3):

`flashlight = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)`

This is my torch class

```
class Torch
  def torchOn
    flashlight = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    check = flashlight.lockForConfiguration(nil)
    if check
      flashlight.setTorchMode(AVCaptureModeOn)
      flashlight.unlockForConfiguration
    end
  end

  def torchOff
    flashlight = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    check = flashlight.lockForConfiguration(nil)
    if check
      flashlight.setTorchMode(AVCaptureModeOff)
      flashlight.unlockForConfiguration
    end
  end
end
```

This is the Rakefile part where I added the corresponding framework:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'
require 'rubygems'

begin
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.require
rescue LoadError
end

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'hellworld'

  app.frameworks += [
      'AVFoundation'
  ]

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mode you're using is just missing the 'Flash' or 'Torch' part. The two that I could find were:

```
AVCaptureFlashModeOn
AVCaptureTorchModeOn
```

One of those should work.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2